# jQuery Fitvids not working in Wordpress post pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, video, responsive-design, fitvids

I'm using fitvids (http://fitvidsjs.com/) to make my videos responsive in Wordpress, and so far it's been fairly simple. I have a video on my home page, and the video resizes correctly there, but for some reason fitvids is not working on the post pages!

Here's the basic formula for making fitvids work, according to the documentation on github:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// Target your .container, .wrapper, .post, etc.
$("#thing-with-videos").fitVids();
});
</script>
```

Here's what I did:

1. Triple-checked to make sure jQuery was loading on the home page
   and the post page.
2. Triple-checked to make sure fitvids.js and javascript.js (my custom JS) was
   being called on the home page and the post page.
3. Confirmed that the video was responsive on the home page
4. Here's what the console looks like on the correctly working home page:
   [image: console]

This is my javascript.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("iframe").wrap("<div class='video-container'/>"); 
//wraps a <div class="video-container"> around all iframes in the wordpress post
jQuery(".single-post iframe").wrap("<div class='post-video-container'/>");

jQuery('.video-container').fitVids();
jQuery('.post-video-container').fitVids();
});
```

Unfortunately, the videos on the Wordpress single post aren't responsive, and I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why it's not so. I took a look at the console for the single posts, and I don't notice a difference between it and the home page:

[image: Screenshot of generated code in Chrome]

I've also attempted to just call in
    **jQuery('body').fiVids();** instead of using .video-container and .post-video-container

... and strangely, the video on the home page continues being responsive while the video on the single post is not.

One last thing:
I'm getting **Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL [HTTP PATH] from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/ISdUqOW3XGc. Domains, protocols and ports must match.** as console errors on both home page and single post page. But since I'm getting it on both, I'm not sure this is the problem.

Comment: Are you running that same jQuery on both pages? When I do that, I get duplicate fluid-width-video-wrapper divs. Other than that, your code works for me. If I remove the .single-post wrapper everything works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pftHQ/2/